# How to fix the spacing around certain special characters in Android?

Tags: java, android, fonts

Some specific characters like `♭♯` are not displayed nice in Android. There is a lot of space in front and behind these characters. How to avoid this?

Don't confuse the `♭♯` with `b#`, because then the spacing is correct. But to be perfect, I want the flat and sharp character.

Comment: How does it appear on the emulator? Where are you noticing this?

Comment: This is in all fonts, also on the emulator. I see this when I insert moll or cross special characters in the chords. It is gone when I replace with a normal "b" character or "#" character. The tool is still on google play and people are downloading, so help would be appreciated.